# molecule isocyanurate not drawing correctly

Tags: chemfig

I'm having trouble drawing the Isocyanurate molecule. The link between nitrogen (N) and carbon (C) on the right side does not link correctly, as per the code - it moves a little inbound to the carbon (C).

Thank you!

```
\schemestart 
\chemfig{R-N=C=O + 2 R-N=C=O} \arrow \\ \chemfig{C(=[3]O)(-[1]N(-[2]R)(-[7]C=[1]O))-[6]N(-[5]R)(-[7]C(=[6]O)(-[1]N([2]-)(-[7]R)))} (Isocianurato)
\schemestop
```

[image]

Comment: \chemfig{*6(N(-R)-C(=[6]O)-N(-[7]R)-C(=[1]O)-N(-R)-C(=[3]O)-)}

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart 
\chemfig{R-N=C=O}
\+ 2
\chemfig{R-N=C=O}
\arrow
\chemfig{N*6((-R)-C(=O)-N(-R)-C(=O)-N(-R)-C(=O)-)}
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
(Isocianurato)
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What was the error of the OP's code, can you add it? :)

Comment: @VScode_fanboy The atoms C and N must be linked with a hook. \chemfig{C(=[3]O)(-[1]N(-[2]R)(-[7]C?=[1]O))-[6]N(-[5]R)(-[7]C(=[6]O)(-[1]N?(-[7]R)))}